# Interacting with a third party app from my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Is it possible to interact with a third party (non flutter) android app from my flutter app? The third party app is called metatrader its a free stock and currency trading app , I am planning to make an app which can interact with metatrader android app, but I'm not sure if it's possible

there are some input fields in the metatrader app and I want to paste some data into the metatrader input fields from my app.

If it's possible then what's the best approach?

Comment: You will require certain api(s) to obtain the functionality you've mentioned.and it has noting to do with flutter or native.

Comment: So if the app third party app do not have any public api then there is no way to write the data to it?

Comment: No you cannot acees the data you see on the app , you have to have an api which let you interact with the app's database, please do a little bit of research before asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: can we use a third-party app like camScanner just to click photos I've used the default camera but I want to use another app instead of a camera like some kind of scanning app  @basudevnayak